# Correct CRS for the Ordnance Survey Open Data products

Tags: coordinate-system, data, ordnance-survey

What's the correct CRS for the [***Ordnance Survey Open Data Products***](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html)?
The spatialreference website shows a number of projections identified as `British National Grid`:

```
SR-ORG:6812: BritishNatGrid
SR-ORG:6832: UK National Grid
SR-ORG:6971: Great Britain National Grid with additional Helmert Corrections
SR-ORG:7132: uk nat grid
SR-ORG:7237: test
SR-ORG:7340: test
EPSG:7405: OSGB36 / British National Grid + ODN height
SR-ORG:7415: ordinance survey boundry-line
SR-ORG:7460: osgb:BNG
EPSG:27291: NZGD49 / North Island Grid
EPSG:27292: NZGD49 / South Island Grid
EPSG:27700: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
```

Comment: EPSG:27700: OSGB 1936 / British National Grid

Comment: @T_Bacon Thank you very much; I wanted to find `proj4js` string to use it in [tag:r] while importing boundary shapefiles via `readOGR`.

Comment: Why the heck is it listing two New Zealand CRS??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EPSG code for OS products is epsg:27700. If you need further formats (though that should be enough for any good GIS) you can visit http://epsg.io/27700 which will allow you to download a specific format such as [proj.4](http:////epsg.io/27700.proj4) directly.